# CSS layout z-index centering

Tags: html, css

How do i center an element relative to the parent div and have it overlap the element in that div?

Thanks.

Comment: Not meant to be snarky, but have *what* overlap *which* element in *what* div? Can you clarify?

Comment: Does the parent div have a fixed height? If not, vertical centering with pure css is pretty much impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the best way to achieve vertical centering is to us a table, if not javascript could be used.
with regard to overlapping some sample html explaining your problem will help